# Canvas elements cut off at the

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

When I place a square on the canvas at 0,0 coords the top left is cut off:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
context.rect(0, 0, 200, 100);
context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 7;
context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because half the stroke is inside the rect.fill and **the other half of the stroke is outside the rect.fill**.

Kind of like css borders, you must account for them when sizing/positioning.

In canvas's case, the stroke is always half-in / half-out the object.